# Insert specific ID in identity field

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to insert specific value in identity field in a SQL table?

I deleted some rows and imported them again, but I need to insert some exceptions with exact IDs.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can turn on/off inserting identity values with [SET IDENTITY_INSERT On/Off](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlservercompact/2007/04/13/set-identity_insert-table-name-onoff/):

To enable your custom values:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableName ON
```

To enable auto-values:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableName OFF
```

Note that you have to list the (non-nullable) columns explicitly if you want to insert identity values, like here:

```
INSERT INTO TableName (ID, Text, OtherColumns...) Values (99, 'foo', ...)
```

You **can't** omit the column-list by using this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO TableName Values (99,'foo')
```

Comment: Express 2008.. ahh.. sorry, I misunderstood/misread you. I thought you meant I have to list ALL columns in a table.. I used a list, but omitted just one column...